Problem with Wolfram Engine Grid[] spacing for multiple plots
This is my first post here, so please comment if I need to edit my question with more details.
I am trying to create a grid of multiple plots, and am facing a problem with the spacing.
This works fine:
grid=Grid[Table[Plot[Sin[t],{t,0,1},Frame->True,Axes->False,FrameTicks->False],{y,0,4},{x,0,4}],Spacing->{0,0}]
Export["grid.png",grid]


But if I try to increase the number of columns, the vertical spacing seems to increase suddenly, while the horizontal gap remains the same:
grid=Grid[Table[Plot[Sin[t],{t,0,1},Frame->True,Axes->False,FrameTicks->False],{y,0,4},{x,0,7}],Spacing->{0,0}]
Export["grid.png",grid]


Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? And how I can prevent this problem?
I am using freeware Wolfram Engine CLI (Wolfram Language 14.1.0 Engine for Microsoft Windows (64-bit))

The option should be Spacings rather than Spacing :) . (It's surprising that Grid doesn't warn about this. ) This doesn't resolve the issue, though.

Plot's ImageSize is Automatic so it probably adjust to the page width. E.g. ImageSize -> 300 behaves well.

Another possible solution seems to be setting ItemSize -> All.

Thanks a lot xzczd and Kuba, both solutions work pretty well.

@xzczd Wolfram Cloud shows the error, gut gives no warning upon evaluation: https://i.sstatic.net/meAedhDs.jpg

Turn the comments to an answer. First of all, the option should be Spacings rather than Spacing. It's surprising that Grid doesn't give warning message upon evaluation. In the notebook interface, the invalid option will be colored red, though:

Correcting the option isn't enough to resolve the issue. Two possible solutions are:

Set e.g. ImageSize -> 300 in Plot.

Set  ItemSize -> All in Grid.


